# I can't see ASP.NET Web Page Administration

Tags: webmatrix

I was following Scott Hanselman on Mix11 building the FrontEnd using WebMatrix. http://live.visitmix.com/Keynotes

One of the first things he does is use the ASP.NET Web Page Administration link. When I run WebMatrix that option is not available. I have downloaded the latest version of Web Matrix and the VS tools. I run Web Matrix as an Administrator but still the option is not visible.

What do I need to do to see the Administration link?

Comment: For WebPages v 2 + see http://forums.iis.net/t/1207242.aspx?Can+not+get+to+_admin+page

Answer (score 6):

In order for the Administration page to be accessed, you need at least one ASP.NET Web Pages file in your site - that is, at least one *.cshtml or *.vbhtml file in the **root** directory of the site.

This is because WebMatrix detects these files and only includes the required ASP.NET Web Pages libraries if these files are found.

After you add one of these files, try browsing to your http://localhost:/_Admin again.

Answer (score 0):

In webmatrix 3, I don't see an Administrator links as well, but there is a NuGet package manager on the menu panel and you open it and you can download all the packages you want from it. If you don't have the "NuGet" package manager, Click the "Extensions" on the menu panel and download the "NuGet" package manager first.